# Reordenar níveis de uma variável categórica dentro de painéis de acordo com o grupo ao qual pertencem

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ao usar o comando `fct_reorder(class, hwy, .fun = median)` abaixo, eu pedi para que os níveis da variável `class` fossem reordenados de acordo com a mediana da varíavel `hwy`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = fct_reorder(class, hwy, .fun = median), y = hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ year) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "class")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Entretanto, os níveis de `class` foram reordenados de acordo com as medianas gerais de `class`, e não de `class` por `year`. Ou seja, o painel referente a 1999 aparece, por acaso, como desejo, mas o painel referente a 2008 não. A ordem de *compact* e *midsize* está alterada.

Como posso fazer para que `fct_reorder` entenda que gostaria de reordenar seus níveis por mais de uma variável em sequência?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `tidytext::reorder_within` faz o que precisa:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidytext)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = reorder_within(class, by = hwy, within = year, fun = median), y = hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ year, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "class")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O "truque" por baixo dela é criar um novo fator colando a variável a ser ordenada e a de agrupamento. A `scale_x_reordered` remove o nome do grupo do fator. O equivalente com `fct_reorder` seria:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = fct_reorder(paste(class, year, sep = ":"), hwy, .fun = median), y = hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ year, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(":.*", "", x)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "class")
```

Alternativamente, pode-se usar `interaction` ao invés de `paste`:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = fct_reorder(interaction(class, year), hwy, .fun = median), y = hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ year, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub("\\..*", "", x)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "class")
```

Comment: A ideia de criar um fator novo colando class e year é muito boa. Gostei dessa estratégia.